# Connecting to 2nd gen Cloud SQL on App Engine flexible PHP 7.0 - missing socket

Tags: php, google-app-engine, php-7, app-engine-flexible

I decided to try out PHP 7 on App Engine and have followed instructions [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/using-cloud-sql) to connect to second gen Cloud SQL but I'm unable to get it working.

As a testing script I decided to upload PhpMyAdmin and got the following error upon attempting to login:

[image: PhpMyAdmin error]

Then I decided to go into debug mode and see what's going on. Turns out that the proxy container is running, the `/cloudsql/` folder is created but there is no socket there:

[image: no socket on filesystem]

Here is my `app.yaml`:

```
runtime: php
env: flex

manual_scaling:
    instances: 1

env_variables:
    CLOUDSQL_UNIX_SOCKET: /cloudsql/project-161108:us-east1:clod-sql-test

beta_settings:
    cloud_sql_instances: "project-161108:us-east1:clod-sql-test"
```

Here is Cloud SQL instance info (yes, I misspelled cloud when creating it):

[image: Cloud SQL properties]

My question is: how can I make the socket appear where it's supposed to be? I've spent 2 days trying to fix this, any advice would be appreciated....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My hypothesis is that the Google Cloud SQL API is not enabled.

Go to the following link and see if it's enabled. Enable it if not.

https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/sqladmin.googleapis.com/overview?project=_

Then try re-deploying the app (unfortunately you need to deploy it again).

Comment: It was actually disabled -.- I expected it to be enabled (similar to how when you go to compute engine it first enables the api). Currently deploying again (for like 30th time :D )

Comment: The guide has the button for enabling that API, so if you exactly follow the guide, it should work, but it's easy to miss because there are similar buttons on every past guides. I would miss it too.

Comment: Hmmm, now the socket file is there but I get the exact same error from PMA.... I will try to redeploy now

Comment: The socket file is there, so it's a progress :)

Comment: @Xymanek Is it possible for you to invite tmatsuo@google.com to your project so that I can quickly debug the issue?

Comment: Turns out that the error is with PhpMyAdmin, using PDO or mySQLi manually works perfectly. I'll see if I can figure out why PMA doesn't find the socket... Thanks for the help!

Comment: Seems like PMA is using mysqli. I think you can specify the default socket in php.ini.


php.ini
mysqli.default_socket= '/cloudsql/CONNECTION_NAME'