# Cannot connect to cloud sql instance from google app engine flexible environment PHP project

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

i am trying to deploy a test php project on google app engine flexible environment.

My app.yaml looks like this:

*

```
runtime: php
env: flex
service: testphpflex
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
#[START cloudsql_settings]
# Use the connection name obtained when configuring your Cloud SQL instance.
beta_settings:
    cloud_sql_instances: "my-first-project:us-central1:tempdb"
#[END cloudsql_settings]
```

*

The composer.json looks like this:

```
{
    "require": {
        "silex/silex": "^1.3",
        "php": "5.6.*",
        "google/apiclient": "^2.0"

    },
    "require-dev": {
        "google/cloud-tools": "^0.6",
        "paragonie/random_compat": "^2.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4"
    }
}
```

And my sample code looks like this:

```
<?php
 $conn = mysql_connect('unix_socket:/cloudsql/my-first-project:us-central1:tempdb',
         'username', 
         'password'
     );

     echo "<br><br/>connection done";
if(!$conn)
{
die('Connection Failed'.mysql_error());
}
else 
{
die('Connection successful');
}

?>
```

However, i am not able to connect. What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Cloud Support tells me that mysql_connect is deprecated. It has been deprecated in PHP since 5.5 and so there is no support for this. So the above is not supported.

Comment: Wow. Would be cool to get a deprecation warning instead of total failure with a vague message.

Answer (score 2):

My hypothesis is that the Google Cloud SQL API is not enabled.

Go to the following link and see if it's enabled. Enable it if not.

https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/sqladmin.googleapis.com/overview?project=_

Then try re-deploying the app (unfortunately you need to deploy it again). If this is the case, it's a dup of [Connecting to 2nd gen Cloud SQL on App Engine flexible PHP 7.0 - missing socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42784800/connecting-to-2nd-gen-cloud-sql-on-app-engine-flexible-php-7-0-missing-socket)

Comment: The APIs are enabled. I am using the same cloud sql instance in other java based app engine projects and there i have no problems.

Comment: When did it happen? We had an issue around cloud sql proxy this week, but now it's fixed. Redeploying might solve it.

Comment: No luck. Still get the same error -- No such file or directory

Comment: I added a right answer above. This question should be closed.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand why you're getting the error.

You should use:

```
mysql_connect(':/cloudsql/my-first-project:us-central1:tempdb',
```

or

```
mysql_connect('localhost:/cloudsql/my-first-project:us-central1:tempdb',
```

According to the manual
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Comment: Google Cloud Support tells me that mysql_connect is deprecated. It has been deprecated in PHP since 5.5 and so there is no support for this. We have finally decided to migrate to PDOs. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Alright, can you mark this question as solved or closed?

Comment: after converting to PDO, is it working. ? I also having the same issue ?

Comment: It's happening because your configuration is wrong. Both mysql_connect and PDO should work.